perpetual motion question
If you had a wheel filled with air vertically half inserted in water tank would it rotate through the buoyance made by gravity pushing pressure on the water making the density of the water more than the wheel?
i believe in the laws of physics and have read them but it still feels like it could work, because of the difference in density between the water and the wheel cycle submerging in and out the water.
I have debated with ChatGPT about it and it keeps saying that it would stop through friction but what I don't understand is why it would then have even initially started rotation and then just go to a stop rotation that seems weird as it started when not in motion
anyways I would like a clear explanation about this
better explaination:
have a hollow wheel that gets more thin making sharp edges made of light but durable material pump it fully up with air
make a precise gap where the half of the wheel fits in the water container
pierce the wheel in the middle with rods attached to the water container allowing loose rotation of the wheel

also the wheel is inserted with a rod able to rotate bit important probably

Re, "also the wheel is inserted..." If you want to add details to your question, then you should edit them into the main body of the question instead of appending them in a comment.

I've cleaned up your question a bit. Please avoid unnecessary and self deprecating remarks  in the future when posting here.

Re, "it still feels like it could work because..." Can you also explain what "work" means? What would "working" look like? Are you expecting the wheel to start turning on its own? Are you expecting that the wheel would continue turning forever? (probably "yes" to that one, eh?) Are you expecting that you could attach something to the shaft of the wheel so that it not only continues to turn forever, but also does something useful like drive an electrical generator?

i know its silly and already clarified im stupid

This question is similar to: Why doesn't this perpetual motion machine using the buoyant force work?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Whatever energy you gain from having something spontaneously float due to buoyancy, you have to spend to re-insert the buoyant object at the bottom of the reservoir. You can collect energy from something floating exactly once - if you want to repeat the process, you have to reset the mechanism by spending an identical amount of energy to make it sink, leaving you exactly where you started.
You can't just slip a buoyant object beneath a column of water "for free" any more than you can put a book on the bottom of a stack without lifting the stack. This is usually the part that's overlooked when considering this type of perpetual motion machine - there is no way to get the floating object back to the bottom without spending energy.
See also: Why will this plan for a perpetual motion device not work?

yea your right i already also thought about friction losses and that prob the water resists because viscosity so yeah thanks for the explaining i kinda needed to hear it from a person now i can finally stop thinking about this stupid idea
